# Using GNU GLOBAL and gtags-cscope in vim

Tags: vimrc, ctags, cscope

Now I am learning how to use GNU GLOBAL in vim. I have installed `gtags.vim`. I have `gtags` the kernel source directory. The `.vimrc` includes the following lines:

```
set cscopetag
set csprg=gtags-cscope                                             
cs add GTAGS
```

Assume that I am editing the file `arch/x86/kvm/x86.c` and the cursor is on the function call `kvm_lapic_enabled()`. Now I press `^]`, the vim complains like this:

```
E429: File "arch/x86/kvm/lapic.h" does not exist
E257: cstag: tag not found
```

If I remove the `set cscopetag` in `.vimrc`, the vim will complains like this:

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: kvm_lapic_enabled
```

So I guess that in the first case, vim used the tag file generated by gtags to locate the function and learned that it is defined in `arch/x86/kvm/lapic.h`. However, vim seems to lookup this file under current directory, that is `arch/x86/kvm/arch/x86/kvm/lapic.h`, when using cscope by default.
So how to configure vim to let `^]` can utilize the GTAGS correctly? Exactly, how to configure the `cscope find` command to use the GTAGS correctly?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Here are the things I've done to get `gtags-cscope` to work properly within Vim. Execute `cs add GTAGS <project-directory> -a` where `<project-directory>` is the name of the directory in which `gtags` was run and in which `GTAGS` resides. The `-a` flag tells `gtags-cscope` to output absolute file names. Also `let $GTAGSDBPATH = <project-directory>` and `let $GTAGSROOT = <project-directory>`.

Comment: @garyjohn I add `cs add GTAGS $PWD` to solve this problem now. However, you have to open vim under the root directory of the project.

Comment: Or you could have Vim figure out what the root directory of the current project is and set the third argument to `cs add` accordingly. How you do that depends on how and where you start Vim and on how your projects are structured. I have a script that uses the directory in which Vim starts to figure out the current project directory. If no project directory is found, as when starting Vim in $HOME, then the script uses the full path of the first file opened in a project to determine the project directory. There are also some scripts at `vim.sourceforge.net` for doing this.

Comment: @garyjohn Yes, scripts like that will be helpful and convenient. Thanks very much!

Comment: @garyjohn your https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4991/using-gnu-global-and-gtags-cscope-in-vim#comment7614_4991 worked great for me --- thanks!